# Mysql 8 custom string function always returns zero

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-8.0

I'm stuck on this for a while now. I wrote a simple slugify UDF in MySQL8 that makes use of the built-in [regexp_replace()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function.

The syntax of the function is valid, but it always returns 0 (zero), for every input.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `slugify`(dirty_string varchar(200)) RETURNS varchar(200) CHARSET utf8mb4
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE slug varchar(200);

   SET slug = REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER(dirty_string), '[éèêë€]','e');
   SET slug = REGEXP_REPLACE(slug, '[áàâä@]','a');
   SET slug = REGEXP_REPLACE(slug, '[îï]','i');
   SET slug = REGEXP_REPLACE(slug, '[üµù]','u');
   SET slug = REGEXP_REPLACE(slug, '[öôØøº]','o');
   SET slug = REGEXP_REPLACE(slug, '[ç]','c');
   SET slug = REGEXP_REPLACE(slug, '[^a-z0-9\-]+','-');

RETURN slug;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I first suspected the special characters that may caused the trouble, but simplifying the function gives the same result:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `slugify`(dirty_string varchar(200)) RETURNS varchar(200) CHARSET utf8mb4
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE slug varchar(200);

   SET slug = REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER(dirty_string), 'x','a');

RETURN slug;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

To verify the syntax, i tried to replace the regexp_replace function with a string and that worked just fine, so the problem only occurs when regexp_replace() is assigned to a variable or return value in a custom function.

The documentation doesn't say that you can't use regexp_replace in a udf, so why is this returning 0 without any errors or warnings?

Comment: What if you add the `CHARSET` modifier to the declarations of `dirty_string` and `slug`?

Comment: Good point. Just tried it out, but still got zero as result.

Comment: What happens if you use `REPLACE()` instead fo `REGEXP_REPLACE()`?

Comment: Your much simplified version works fine on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=266438c152b72cffdf68016b3ed1165e)

Comment: And so does the complete version: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=814e49de578a809664c4d0e1900c2d1b

Comment: What is this? I immediately doublechecked my db version. It's 8.0.11, and i can't get this function to work. Could this be related to certain db settings?

Answer (score 0):

Since some comments suggested that this function works correctly in dbfiddle, i started doing some research on the versions used on dbfiddle and my own server.

This slugify function works fine in mysql 8.0.12, but not in mysql 8.0.11. I found 2 related bugs regarding regexp_replace() that were fixed in 8.0.12:

- [regexp_replace accumulating result](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90803)
- [regexp_replace truncate update](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90870)

I updated my server to 8.0.12 and got the function working.